# Table exported as pdf from jupyter notebook is not printed

Tags: pandas, dataframe, printing, jupyter-notebook, export-to-pdf

I have a nice Jupyter notebook in which a pandas dataframe is pretty-printed as table...

[image: This is from web browser]

...Then I exported to PDF, discarding the input cells to generate a kind of report of results and stuff. I do so by using this command and got the result below, which although it is not a latex table, is enough for now, but...

```
$ jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --to=pdf --TemplateExporter.exclude_input=True
```

[image: This is from the PDF viewer]

... when I print the PDF file, nothing is printed where the tables should be, just empty space but the format of the other components (paragraphs, figures) is OK.

I'm not sure where in the whole chain the problem is...

**- Is it the formatting of the table in the notebook?**

I have tried some HTML and LaTeX functions around the dataframe, but what I get in the pdf is the source HTML or LaTeX.

**- Is there any exporting issue?**
I get a warning from the `$ jupyter` command:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/nbconvert/utils/pandoc.py:52: RuntimeWarning: You are using an unsupported version of pandoc (2.6).
Your version must be at least (1.12.1) but less than (2.0.0).
Refer to http://pandoc.org/installing.html.
Continuing with doubts...
```

**- Could it be printing problems?**

I am using a printer HP Laserjet m551 from Ubuntu 16.04

Anyway, what I would like is to print a LaTeX or HTML style table, but at this point even if it prints what I see on the pdf, it's fine.

Any guidance is really appreciated!

Comment: The warning is because you're using an outdated version of `pandoc`. Upgrade it from [here](http://pandoc.org/installing.html). I'm not sure why it's happening but you may try a different printer.

Comment: Hi @harshit_k, actually the warning is because pandoc is very updated, I have 2.6 but as the message states: `Your version must be at least (1.12.1) but less than (2.0.0)`. Changing printer is an option, I will try it home because at work is the only one available.

Comment: Oh sorry @gustavovelascoh, I misread it.